# Uploading a file with a dash "-" in the name using IFormFile

Tags: asp.net-core

I'm familiar with working with IFormFile to upload files to my .net core API, but I have a peculiar situation where the name of the file is being sent with a dash in it, and i can't use a dash in the Action parameter name. How do i use filters to CHANGE the name of the file. I tried looking into manipulating the HTTPCONTEXT with an ActionFilter, but the file name is READ ONLY. What do I do?? I need this to map to my dash-less parameter name.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

File name doesn't matter for model binding, but `input` name does. Just use name without a dash

```html
<input type="file" name="thefile" />
```

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult(IFormFile thefile)
```

In the case your `input` name contains a dash you can specify the name using model binding attributes

```cs
[HttpPost]
public IActionResult([FromForm(Name = "file-with-dash")] IFormFile file)
```

Comment: That worked wonderfully. I wasn't aware I could use model binding attributes in that way! Thank you @Alexander -- you're a genius!